# BrowserFactory.spawnMozilla() return null

Tags: java, null

I used WebRenderer in the code ,the program running in the RedHat platform ,and the Firefox broswer installed in the platform ,but when execute to the lines with BrowserFactory.spawnMozilla() ,it returns null .
Anyone who can tell me how this can be happened ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla can only be spawned if you have downloaded the enterprise version (6mb). This version includes the Micro version. The enterprise version runs off local components that are distributed with WebRenderer and requires no software to be installed on the computer to make WebRenderer run. WebRenderer full distribution is a self contained HTML browser. WebRenderer Micro relies on Internet Explorer (on Windows) or Safari (on OSX) to be on the users system. The Micro edition uses Internet Explorer or Safari libraries to display HTML. The Mozilla based enterprise WebRenderer build runs on multiple platforms including Windows, Linux, OSX, JavaDesktop and Solaris.

This is taken from here http://www.webrenderer.com/products/desktop/developer/examples/createbrowser.php